# On/off Circuit with an AVR and a push button

Tags: transistors, avr, switches, relay

Here is maybe a difficult question I mind asking but here we are, I need to do a Power On/Power Off switch with an attiny 2313 and a push button, the code is ok, but I want this "switch" to power on purpose a HD44780 4x20 LCD, an atmega1284, multiple Leds and 1 RF434 Emitter and a receiver on the other side is the attiny 2313, an FTDI FT232BL and an enc28j60 coupled with an atmega328 so I want or the FT232BL or the enc28J60 via WOL or the push button to power on the LCD and the atmega1284. But my question is how to do it?

I thought of an NPN transistor (like the 2N2222A)  but unfortunately it doesn't drive a lot of current and a relay but I don't pretty like (and my current is pretty limited if USB powered) this option, any other idea ? (here is a basic schema of what I want to do, I remove almost every component related to each chip for better 'reading')

[image: schematic]

Comment: I've just included the schematic as a clickable link, but maybe you could review the question to make it clearer what you're trying to do. You can press the edit button at any time to make any changes / clarifications, I found it a bit hard to follow the end result you're after.

Comment: But upon a further look at the schematic I guess you just want a way to replace the 2N2222 with something like a FET that will handle more current and have a lower voltage drop?

Comment: Yep, I will try to do it more clear a bit later, but yeah I'd like to handle more current even with a bit lower voltage(if I can go at 3.3V max it would be perfect)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace the 2N2222 with a P-mosfet and drive the gate with a small transistor that will operate as a level translator so that you can control the mosfet with voltages at a level of 3v or lower.

[image]

The load represents the devices you are going to power from the mosfet output.

You should select a logic level P-mosfet that can be turned  on fully with a Vgs of -5v and have a current capability high enough for your application.

The resistor values can change if you have different needs but for static operation and low consumption the provided values should be good enough (about 0.2mA base current with 3v base voltage and about 0.4mA collector current)

Comment: Thanks ! I just have to found the perfect Mosfet, just had to head to farnell now.